# Where's the all actions history for all my "actions" on documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

I looked on my main account all actions/all but only found the badges I earned, and I'm looking for my previous actions that and check if they are still being handled. Basically, where's the thing I can check for an user actions on documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it in your profile, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation). Just like you have a tab for questions, and one for answers, you have one for documentation.
Once there, you can drill into proposed changes, topic drafts, topic requests, requests for improvement, contributions and all of those.